# Samza build with gradle failing

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, gradlew, apache-samza

Samza build with gradle is failing while executing testing with on samza-core.

Below is the exception I am facing:

Please share your thoughts...

```
org.apache.samza.config.factories.TestPropertiesConfigFactory > testCanReadPropertiesConfigFiles FAILED
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in authority at index 7: file://C:apache-samza-0.9.1-src\samza-core/src/test/resources/test.
properties
        at java.net.URI.create(URI.java:859)
        at org.apache.samza.config.factories.TestPropertiesConfigFactory.testCanReadPropertiesConfigFiles(TestPropertiesConfigFactory.scala:34)
        Caused by:
        java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in authority at index 7: file://C:\Users\z013sqm\Downloads\apache-samza-0.9.1-src\samza-core/src/test/resources/test.pro
perties
            at java.net.URI$Parser.fail(URI.java:2829)
            at java.net.URI$Parser.parseAuthority(URI.java:3167)
            at java.net.URI$Parser.parseHierarchical(URI.java:3078)
            at java.net.URI$Parser.parse(URI.java:3034)
            at java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:595)
            at java.net.URI.create(URI.java:857)
            ... 1 more
125 tests completed, 2 failed, 2 skipped
Finished generating test XML results (0.062 secs) into: C:\Users\z013sqm\Downloads\apache-samza-0.9.1-src\samza-core\build\test-results
Generating HTML test report...
Finished generating test html results (0.128 secs) into: C:\Users\z013sqm\Downloads\apache-samza-0.9.1-src\samza-core\build\reports\tests
:samza-core_2.10:test FAILED
:samza-core_2.10:test (Thread[Daemon,5,main]) completed. Took 11.229 secs.
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':samza-core_2.10:test'.
> There were failing tests. See the report at: file:///C:apache-samza-0.9.1-src/samza-core/build/reports/tests/index.html
* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --debug option to get more log output.
BUILD FAILED**
```

Answer (score 1):

Samza's not tested or built on Windows.  There's no reason it can't run there, it's just that no one has done the work to smooth out the multiplatform assumptions (like the one you're running into regarding paths).  Patches welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced a similar problem and the solution for me was commenting the  testTTL call in TestRocksDBKeyValueStore.scala and re-run the gradle script. Try If it works for you.